# Can I have an excel formula reference a cell from another formula?

Tags: excel, csv

I have a very large excel sheet that I am running formulas on. I run a formula on every item in the sheet and then remove the duplicates leaving me with only the unique items. Is there a way that I can have a second formula automatically reference the cell from the first formula?

Formula 1:

```
=INDEX(Radnet_Master_LocationList.xlsx!$A$2:$A$265, MATCH(***'1611029532'!G2***,Radnet_Master_LocationList.xlsx!$B$2:$B$265,0))
```

Formula 2:

```
=SUMIFS('1611029532'!AS$2:AS$1867,'1611029532'!G$2:G$1867,***'1611029532'!G2***)
```

I have enclosed the cells that need to match with 3 ***. When I copy the second formula into all of the cells needed, that cell increments and I would like it to mirror the cell from the first formula. For example, say '1611029532'!G369 comes right after '1611029532'!G2 in the first formula. When I increment the second formula it ends up as '1611029532'!G3, when I want it to be '1611029532'!G369.

Comment: I *think* you could use `indirect()`, but can you clarify what you mean by "For example, say '1611029532'!G369 comes right after '1611029532'!G2 in the first formula"?

Comment: Sure. When I first run the formula on all items in the sheet it increments by 1 each time, but then when I remove the duplicate values it does not increment in a set order.